# release_handle - detect double release

Tags: c, clang, static-analysis, scan-build

I'm trying to get a handle (du-dum-tsh) on clang's `acquire_handle` and `release_handle` [attributes](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#handle-attributes).  I've written

```c
int create_foo(void) __attribute__((acquire_handle("foo")));
void destroy_foo(int __attribute__((release_handle("foo"))) foo);

void func(void)
{
    int foo = create_foo();
    destroy_foo(foo);
    destroy_foo(foo);
}
```

Though it compiles just fine, why doesn't

```bash
scan-build clang -c foo.c
```

detect the double release?

This is clang 14.0.0.